# ReorderListView-Items disappear when moved

Tags: android, xamarin

ReorderListView for Android from Xamarin Components.

Problem:
Cells disappear when dragged around. Only happens on Devices running Lollipop (So far I've seen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've forgott to override a specific method in the adapter.

```
public override bool HasStableIds
{
    get { return true; }
}
```

This had the strange behavior that it worked on Kitkat but not on Lollipop.